# Why this works(JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I was working on one of my projects and had to check if any of the coordinates in two arrays(of the same length) at the same index are the exact same or not. I know there are few methods to do this but I came across one that started to rise my curiosity. Why does it work? 
So here is a syntax -

```
 exports.check = (arr1, arr2) => {
  for(var i = arr1.length; i--;) {
    if(arr1[i] !== arr2[i])
        return true; //If none of the points are the same
  }return false; //If some of the points are the same
}
```

By my knowledge return statement should stop/break the loop and return the first value in any case. True or not. But it does not... Can someone explain what am I missing here?

Comment: It does break the loop if any of them are not equal at the same position.

Comment: There's an if block right there, as soon as it discovers there's not a match it'll return true.

Comment: the comments in the code are wrong. It return true if any are not the same, if all are the same it returns false

Comment: Why are you expecting it should break at the first iteration already?

Comment: "Return the first value in any case" - eh? This code returns true upon the first time it encounters a pair of array values that differ, or it returns false if the iteration of the array runs to completion without finding a difference

Comment: Also, just to be a contrarian, a simple `console.log(i)` as the first statement of the for loop would tell you how many times it loops, without a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: At most this code is incorrect in case arr2 is larger than arr1 but has the same values as arr1 + some more (but without knowing what it is supposed to check, it's hard to tell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably confused with the way the `if` block is appearing. You can avoid brackets if the result after an `if` check is a one-liner. It does return true only and only when there is **not** a match.

This:

```
 exports.check = (arr1, arr2) => {
  for(var i = arr1.length; i--;) {
    if(arr1[i] !== arr2[i])
        return true; //If none of the points are the same
  }return false; //If some of the points are the same
}
```

is the same as:

```
 exports.check = (arr1, arr2) => {
  for(var i = arr1.length; i--;) {
    if(arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) {
        return true; 
    }
  }
 return false; 
}
```

P.S: The comments in your code are wrong and the code as well. This is just to explain the about the `if` block

Comment: Yeah :D. I just realized that the first bracket after if the statement is a closing bracket for a loop and not IF statement. Haha. Thank you guys for opening my eyes :D

Comment: There is some time where I need to approve the answer after posting a question. Will do it!

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to understand if presented thus:

```
//returns true if arrays differ or false if arrays are same
exports.arraysAreDifferent = (arr1, arr2) =>
{
  for(var i = arr1.length; i>=0; i--) {
    if(arr1[i] !== arr2[i]){
        return true; //if even one pair of array values differ, arrays are different 
    } else {
      //do nothing/check next pair 
    }
  }

  return false; //Loop finished without finding difference. Arrays are same
}
```

The comments were a bit misleading, and the indentation/bracketing/putting return false after the girly bracket that closed the loop might have been a confusing read that made it look like it was "if x then return this else return that" so you may have pondered how would the loop run to completion. It runs because there is no else; if the if test always fails the loop runs through every pair